# Warning: Undefined array key "nombre" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Compramas\php\enviarcomentarios.php on line 2

Tags: php, html, css, formularios, post

Intento hacer un código que envié un comentario a otra página pero me aparece estos errores

> Warning: Undefined array key "nombre" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Compramas\php\enviarcomentarios.php on line 2

> Warning: Undefined array key "comentario" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Compramas\php\enviarcomentarios.php on line 3

Este es el codigo de **enviarcomentarios.php**

```
<?php
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

    echo($nombre);
    echo($comentario);
?>
```

Y este el codigo de mi formulario en **index.php**

```
<form id="formulario" action="php/enviarcomentarios.php" method="POST">
            <h3>Comentarios</h3>
    ********<input id="com-nombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
    ********<textarea id="coment-input" placeholder="Escriba su comentario"></textarea>
            <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Publicar">
    </form>

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
<!-- ////////////////////////////// -->

<script language="javascript">
    $("#enviar").click(function(){
    var nombre = $('#com-nombre').val();
    var comentario = $('#coment-input').val();

    if (nombre==""){
        alert("Debe escribir un nombre")
        return;
    }
    if (comentario==""){
        alert("Debe escribir un comentario")
        return;
    }

    $("#formulario").submit();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás enviando los parámetros cuando haces el método POST. Para enviarlo correctamente, se deberá agregar el atributo `name` en tus campos, sería algo así:

```
<input id="com-nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
<textarea id="coment-input" name="comentario" placeholder="Escriba su comentario"></textarea>
```

Así, en tu método POST enviará el contenido de tus campos y en tu archivo PHP lo recibirá de manera correcta.

```
<?php
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

    echo($nombre);
    echo($comentario);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En el form tienes que colocar los names, estos deben coincidir con lo que colocas en PHP dentro del _POST['..']

```
<form id="formulario" action="php/enviarcomentarios.php" method="POST">
            <h3>Comentarios</h3>
    *******<input name="nombre" id="com-nombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
    ********<textarea name="comentario" id="coment-input" placeholder="Escriba su comentario"></textarea>
            <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Publicar">
    </form>
```